# How to use validationDefault method in cakephp 3

Tags: php, validation, cakephp-3.0

I am trying to use validationDefault method in my model UsersTable :

```
<?php
namespace App\Model\Table;
use Cake\ORM\Table;
use Cake\Validation\Validator;
class UsersTable extends Table
{

    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');
        $this->setTable('users');
        $this->setPrimaryKey('id');
    }

    public function validationDefault(Validator $validator)
    {
        $validator->add('login', [
            'length' => [
                'rule' => ['minLength',3],
                'message' => __('Login need to be at least 3 characters long')
            ]
        ]);

        return $validator;
    }
}
```

In my Users controller i have the following code :

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller;
use Cake\Validation\Validator;

class UsersController extends AppController {

    public function initialize() {
        parent::initialize();
    }
    public function add() {

        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $user = $this->Users->newEntity($this->request->getData());
            if ($this->Users->save($user)) {
                $this->Flash->success(__('Your user has been created.'));
                return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
            }
            $this->Flash->error(__('Unable to create your user.'));

    }
```

My form looks like :

```
<?= $this->Form->create('Users', ['url' => ['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'add']]); ?>

    <fieldset>
        <legend><?= __('Ajouter un utilisateur') ?></legend>
        <?= $this->Form->control('login') ?>
        <?= $this->Form->control('password') ?>
        <?= $this->Form->control('role', [
            'options' => ['admin' => 'Admin', 'author' => 'Author']
        ]) ?>
    </fieldset>
<?= $this->Form->button(__('Ajouter')); ?>
<?= $this->Form->end() ?>
```

If I use form with "aa" in login form, data are insert in database. But they should not be insert because validator define minLength to 3.

It's seem like validationDefault is not call when I use save method.

Here a debug of var $user :

```
object(Cake\ORM\Entity) {

    'login' => 'g',
    'password' => '',
    'role' => 'admin',
    '[new]' => true,
    '[accessible]' => [
        '*' => true
    ],
    '[dirty]' => [
        'login' => true,
        'password' => true,
        'role' => true
    ],
    '[original]' => [],
    '[virtual]' => [],
    '[errors]' => [],
    '[invalid]' => [],
    '[repository]' => 'Users'

}
```

**Note**: if I use validator directly in controller, an error is print : Login need to be at least 3 characters long.But i don't want use validator directly in controller...

```
$validator = new Validator();
        $validator->add('login', [
            'length' => ['rule' => ['minLength', 3],
                'message' => __('Login need to be at least 3 characters long')
            ]
        ]);
        if($validator->errors($this->request->getData())) {
                debug($validator->errors($this->request->getData()));
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I ask this problem to channel #cakephp on IRC and they say to me to reinstall cakephp but using bake to generate model classes.

After that, all is working fine.